# ReCaptcha doesn't show on Simplenews Subscription Block

Tags: 8, captcha

I have the subscription form of Simplenews in the footer, which should be protected with reCaptcha. I installed reCaptcha and created a captcha point with the form ID of the Simplenews block. Unfortunately, I don't see the recaptcha on the Simplenews registration block in the footer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the issue also occur when using the Drupal default olivero/bartik theme?

Comment: You need to log out. And you need the domain allowed in your reCaptcha settings on Google. Did you do both?

Comment: Yes, the same issue with olivero/bartik theme. I also checked it on another browser which I wasn't logged in. I added reCaptcha on Google yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem. The ID of the form was too long. It seems that the ID can be a maximum of 64 characters long.